# How to reset the p-columnfilter in PrimeNG 14

Tags: angular, primeng, angular14, primeng-datatable

What my objective here is when I click on clear button it should clear the input and should load previous records. [This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPsrc.png). Is there any builtin function in PrimeNG for this.

I had modified the columnfilter like this in image and apply is working but clear is not working.

```html
<p-columnFilter type="text" field="notificationType" display="menu" [showMatchModes]="false" matchMode="contains" [showOperator]="false" [showAddButton]="false"></p-columnFilter>
```